# FadeIn/FadeOut Inserted/Deleted Row with jQuery AJAX

Tags: c#, php, jquery, asp.net, ajax

My question is using `fadeIn` with `jQuery AJAX` in a news portal comment system. I have #table that is id of ul, and each comment is listed as a listitem inside this div. Whenever someone writes a new comment, the new comment must be inserted into the webpage as a fadeIn animation. (and whenever someone deletes an answer, the listitem must be removed as fadeOut)

Thank you.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'WebForm1.aspx',
  success: function(data){
    $('#table').html(data);
  }
});
```

---

```
<ul id="table" runat="server">
    <li>Comment 1</li>
    <li>Comment 2</li>
    <li>Comment 3</li>
    <li>Comment 4</li> // <--- can jQuery AJAX detect "ONLY" the inserted listitem and display it with fadeIn animation.
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't return the whole comments table in the AJAX request, only the comment that is updated.

Then just do:

```
success: function(data){
  $('#table').append(data).find('li').last().hide().fadeIn();
}
```

Although, this would only obviously fadeIn the last comment - so if you've got more than one new one (or no new comments) you'll need to do something like this:

```
success: function(data){
  if(data){ //or some other test to ensure there is new comments
     var $table = $('#table');
     $table.children().addClass('no-anim');
     $table.append(data);
     $table.children(':not(.no-anim)').hide().fadeIn();
  }
}
```